# Floating Action Button won't stay on top of SnackBar

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button, android-support-design, snackbar

I've been dealing with this problem for days. I simply can't make the FloatingActionButton to go on top of the SnackBar.

I've seen a lot of tutorials .. Tried everything.

I hope that someone can help me here:

My layout is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!-- Your Scrollable View -->

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_start"
            app:fabSize="normal"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My activity code is:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setupToolbar();
        setupFab();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if(drawerLayout != null)
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupNavigationView(){

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    }

    private void setupFab(){
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        if(fab != null)
            fab.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void setupToolbar(){
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if(toolbar != null)
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Show menu icon
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(view.getId() == R.id.fab){

            Snackbar
              .make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout), "This is Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
              .setAction("Action", this)
              .show(); // Don�t forget to show!
        }
    }
}
```

The result is this one:

[image: result]

Comment: May i know what scrollable view you are using?

Comment: Follow this guide: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Comment: It is a ViewPager @Sree14. And each of the fragments have a recyclerView

Comment: @FábioCarballo Have you found an answer? I'm having the same issue when I try to click the button multiple times.

Comment: @SrikarReddy hey, to me the problem was with proguard.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the coordinatorLayout, but actually you need the FloatingActionButton's view :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.fab) {
        Snackbar .make(view, "This is Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG) .setAction("Action", this) .show();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this attribute in your FloatingActionButton(FAB):

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/coordinatorLayout"
```

This should associate the FAB with your CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: View can not be anchored to the the parent CoordinatorLayout```